# Getting rendered font dimensions in Adobe Text Layout Framework

Tags: apache-flex, flash, tlf

I'm currently struggling with implementing text floating in TLF. It does not support it natively, and the only solution I've found so far is to use linked containers and then combine controllers using flowComposer for single textFlow.

However, I need to implement Dropped Initial letter feature in my column layout. Initial is just a first big letter in paragraph, floated by the rest of the text. It looks like this -

[image]

The issue here is that for that big letter, the resulting TLF textFlow sprite is bigger than the actual letter. It's because of the baselines (small q vs big A for example). But I don't want these extra gaps. After textFlow is rendered, I would like to learn how big the resulting letter exactly is (in pixels) so that I can crop/shift baseline, etc.

ContainerController.getContentBounds().height or
ContainerController.compositionHeight

gives me height of whole sprite with gaps added, not the letter.

Is there some kind of measure method for this?
Can this be solved differently?

Answer (score 0):

check out the Tiny TLF framework by Paul Taylor. I think he addressed this issue along with many other cool things.

Check it out: https://github.com/trxcllnt/tinytlf

Comment: The link is dead, unfortunately. I wasn't in touch with TLF recently, so it could be that the issue is solved already.

Comment: If the answer was sufficient please flag as answered